# Using Google Drive API - how to show a list of folders in root folder

Tags: android, google-drive-api

I am trying to create an Android App so that the user can browse and select files from their Google Drive.

I am totally new to Android and I have been mostly trying to use the samples.
When I run the APK on my phone, the authentication seems to work ok, but I am not sure how to retrieve and display the Drive folders.

1. How can they be retrieved?
2. What should they be displayed in (`ListView`?) so that users can navigate to the files?

My onConnected code is working ok, but I think the problem is to do with the DriveId not being populated correctly.

```
@Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
        Log.i(TAG, "API client connected.");
        super.onCreate(connectionHint);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_listfiles);
        mResultsListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewResults);
        mResultsAdapter = new ResultsAdapter(this);
        mResultsListView.setAdapter(mResultsAdapter);


        Drive.DriveApi.fetchDriveId(getGoogleApiClient(), EXISTING_FOLDER_ID)
                .setResultCallback(idCallback);

    }
```

I have a layout called "activity_listfiles.xml".  On that layout is it just a ListView called: @id/listViewResults

The code is going into this method as I am getting the DriveID error message: Cannot find DriveId. Are you authorized to view this file?

```
final private ResultCallback<DriveIdResult> idCallback = new ResultCallback<DriveIdResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onResult(DriveIdResult result) {
        if (!result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
            showMessage("Cannot find DriveId. Are you authorized to view this file?");
            return;
        }
        DriveFolder folder = Drive.DriveApi.getFolder(getGoogleApiClient(), result.getDriveId());
        folder.listChildren(getGoogleApiClient())
                .setResultCallback(metadataResult);
    }
};
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?  I am using the following as a guide:
https://github.com/googledrive/android-demos/tree/master/src/com/google/android/gms/drive/sample/demo

Here is the ResultsAdapter java file, I'm not sure what it does or if I need to change it:

```
public class ResultsAdapter extends DataBufferAdapter<Metadata> {

    public ResultsAdapter(Context context) {
        super(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = View.inflate(getContext(),
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, null);
        }
        Metadata metadata = getItem(position);
        TextView titleTextView =
                (TextView) convertView.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
        titleTextView.setText(metadata.getTitle());
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

I should add that the String EXISTING_FOLDER_ID is in a BaseActivity.java, and the line of code looks like:

```
public static final String EXISTING_FOLDER_ID = "0B2EEtIjPUdX6MERsWlYxN3J6RU0";
```

I take it I need to populate this with an ID somehow?

I tried using:

```
    EXISTING_FOLDER_ID =  Drive.DriveApi.getRootFolder(getGoogleApiClient()).getDriveId().toString();

    showMessage(EXISTING_FOLDER_ID);

   Drive.DriveApi.fetchDriveId(getGoogleApiClient(),EXISTING_FOLDER_ID)
            .setResultCallback(idCallback);
```

The showMessage DOES display an ID - so it IS fetching the root folder ID, but for some reason it still shows the "Cannot find DriveID" message.

So the fetchDriveID is failing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see the need of the README here https://github.com/googledrive/android-demos/blob/master/README.md

You need to change EXISTING_FOLDER_ID to point to a the resource id of a Drive folder that your application has access to.  For example, you could create a new folder and then use that ID.

Comment: I tried this. I browsed to my drive folders in chrome, and I took the folder ID from the URL.  I hardcoded this value and still got the same error.  Surely there has to be a way to list a users folders?

Comment: I was also trying to dynamically set the value by trying to get the ID of the root folder like this: EXISTING_FOLDER_ID =  Drive.DriveApi.getRootFolder(getGoogleApiClient()).getDriveId().toString();

Comment: Your app needs to have access to the folder in order to view it, since you have "Drive.File" scope.  Hence why I suggested creating a new file with the app.  Or, you can use the Android OpenFileDialog to pick a folder using your app.

Comment: Note also that I am building the apk and transferring to my phone as the AVD does not work, something about upgrading play services when you run the emulator. I assume the apk is built in debug mode, but it is signed using the default keystore. I assume the SHA1 is ok too b using the command line to generate it for the Google console.

Comment: but surely my app had permission to the folders since when i start the app for the first time, the Google pop-up comes up asking if i want to let the app access my drive.

Comment: With Drive.File scope, your app only has access to the specific files and folders that the user has authorized your app to see, not your entire Drive.  Your app is authorized to see files it creates, or files that the user explicitly selects via one of the Google-provided file pickers, like the OpenFileActivity.

Comment: Thanks - tomorrow I will try using the open file activity or folder picker to see if I can first select a folder that way. I'll report back if it works

Comment: Thanks it looks like the PickFolderwithOpener Activity works, I can select a folder and it displays the ID of that folder in a message.  You can navigate through all the drive folders and press "Select".  How would I call the ListFilesinFolderClass 0 using an 'intent'? How can I pass the folder (drive) ID?

Comment: I marked this question as answered as you were correct about the Drive.File scope.  I have asked another question rather than continue here.  Thanks!